# Safari Browser.. Paragraph Tag Issue

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow

I am building a website for my friend. Been through some issues with debugging. Some of these were sorted out in terms of being compatible with Internet Explorer where initially I ran into some problems with alignment. But then, moving onto Safari, I have a huge bunch of problems. I would like to just start off with one and hope you guys would be kind enough to help me.

Below is my code:

```
     <div id = "welcome_note_cnt_pic">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. </p>

                <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>

        </div>

    #welcome_note_cnt_pic p{
    width:90%;/*IE Correction Do Not Remove*/
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:justify;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:white;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#welcome_note_cnt_pic{
    width:50%;
    height:550px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:trasparent;

    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

In safari, the paragraph just shoots out of the division box, despite the flex property placed in. I have even placed my code through an online CSS Autoprefixer but it does not seem to solve the problem. I have even tried using some word wrap stuff that I searched for but of no use.

Please help!

BTW-- here is a screen shot of this issue taken on a Safari Browser. May be this may help you understand my problem better?

[The screen shot of the problem. Image- Click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tebvc.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly: Do you want the text paragraphs to be positioned next to each other in a 2-column layout? Like this? http://codepen.io/aaaron/pen/QEWdNB

Seems to be working fine on my Safari.

Comment: Yes.. two columns. When I initiate the display:flex css rule, all other browsers automatically contain the two paras and make it look like a two column thing. But not safari... What would you propose please? In the meanwhile, I am just checking out your link....

Comment: Can you be more precise? Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Aaaron, I just saw your link, yes thats the way its intended to be. I dont have the problem with any other browser except for Safari. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Version says: 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: Your Safari version is very old and it doesn't support flexbox without the -webkit vendor prefix. You can see the supported browsers at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: So, would you recommend that I download Safari 9.1?

Comment: Sorry but, just a beginner here and cracking through to some stuff.. please help and advice...

Comment: Aaaron, just to let you know that I have also tried using appropriate vendor prefixes using an online resource for CSS auto prefix - but even that is of no use.... what else could I do please?

Comment: Forget that version of Safari completely as it's very old and nobody is probably using it anymore :)

Comment: Requesting you to recommend a version number. When I go online and search for latest version for safari browser for windows 10, it states 5.1.. what do you recommend please?

Comment: Safari for Windows is obsolete and nobody is using it. Mac users probably have more modern versions. So you don't need to support it.

Comment: Alright/... will check it out.. thank you for your help... have a nice day!